# Try to understand "Calling startActivity from outside of an Activity context"

Tags: android

Need help in understanding this exception:

```
   system_log_all 11-14 11:52:28.540 E/AndroidRuntime(31615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
system_log_all 11-14 11:52:28.540 E/AndroidRuntime(31615): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
system_log_all 11-14 11:52:28.540 E/AndroidRuntime(31615):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:689)
system_log_all 11-14 11:52:28.540 E/AndroidRuntime(31615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
system_log_all 11-14 11:52:28.540 E/AndroidRuntime(31615):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
```

What is the meaning from 'outside of an Activity  context'? I don't think I call 'startActivity' from 'Application' Context, so what does it mean by outside of an activity Context?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you are trying to call startActivity(..) from a class which is not extended Activity class.

Answer (score 8):

To clearify the previous answer, you need to add the following to the intent before starting the activity:

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Then Android will let you start the activity where it pleases you.

Comment: But what if you do really want to resume an old activity instead of creating a new one? What if I want to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT?  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5):

As @thinksteep commented is seem like you are trying to call `startActivity()` from something else then an `Activity`.

Could it be that you are trying to start the activity from a `Service`?

It this is what you are trying to do you should follow the advice in the warning and add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent flags.

The reason for the warning as I see it is that you are trying to start a UI component from something that is not it self a UI component. Most of the time this is not want you want from a usability perspective.

Exceptions could be incoming calls etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's little bit late response.. But just now I came out from same issue. so I would like to post this on public, it may helpful for others who is on same situation. I just used `Myclassname.this` instead of `getApplicationContext();` .